# How can I grab a button's click event in a DaisyUI Collapse title?

Tags: javascript, click, parent-child, svelte, daisyui

I'm trying to do something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/daisyui-sveltekit-furm6v?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte

Here's the code from it:

```
<h1 class='text-xl'>Daisy attempt</h1>

<div class="collapse collapse-arrow">
  <input type="checkbox" /> 
  <div class="collapse-title text-xl font-medium">
    <span class=pr-4>Click me to show/hide content</span>
    <button on:click|stopPropagation={() => alert('saved')} class='btn btn-error'>save changes</button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse-content"> 
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr class=mt-4>

<h1 class='text-xl'>Native components solution</h1>

<details>
  <summary>
    <span class=pr-4>Click me to show/hide content</span>
    <button on:click|stopPropagation={() => alert('saved')} class='btn btn-error'>save changes</button>
  </summary>
  
  details
</details>

<style>
summary:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

I'm not sure if/how to get the button's click handler to run. Any advice?

Thanks

I've tried using z-index but I suppose that's only for `display` not event handling.

I've tried `stopPropagation` on the button but that didn't work either.

Comment: Include all relevant code *inside* the question, do not just link somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue right now is that the `input` element is covering the title div, which is why your clicks are not reaching the button. To fix this we can just change the order a bit and mess with the pointer events.

```css
.collapse-title {
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.collapse-title button {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

this will make sure that the title covers the input, but that clicks fall though to the input while not falling through the button.

Comment: yep, great idea!  I'll discuss the possibility of incorporating this approach into daisyUI with the author.  Thanks!

fwiw, a `z-index` of `1` will get the job done here as well.